# Compile Errors Which I don't know how to fix

Tags: c++

Basically what I have to do is re-make my own c-string. strlen, strcmp, strcpy, and strcat.
The code below is in my header file:

```
int mystrlen(const char pcString[]) //strlen function
{
   const char *pcStringEnd = pcString;

   while (*pcStringEnd != '\0')
      pcStringEnd++;

   return pcStringEnd - pcString;
}

int mystrcmp(char *s1, char *s2) // strcmp function
{
  while(*s1 == *s2)
  {
    if(*s1 == '\0' || *s2 == '\0')
      break;

    first++;
    second++;
  }

  if(*first == '\0' && *second == '\0')
    return (0);
  else
    return (-1);
}

char mystrcpy(char *s1, const char *s2) // strcpy function
{
  while(*s2)
  {
    *s1 = *s2;
    s2++;
    s1++;
  }

 *s1 = '\0';
}

char mystrcat(char *s1, const char *s2) //strcat function
{
  char *string1 = s1;
  const char *string2 = s2;
  char *catString = string1 + string2;
  return catString;
}
```

Most of the errors are identifiers not being defined, but the thing is that I cannot not change what is in my main.cpp. Only the header file can be modified. I would put my main.cpp here but its a long code.

```
{
 char *string1 = s1;
 const char *string2 = s2;
 char *catString = string1 + string2; //There is an error here with string 2 and catring.
 return catString;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the errors too please?

Comment: 1. You didn't put the errors or enough code for us to compile it and see them ourselves. 
2. Why can't you change main.cpp?

Comment: It would be easier to get help if you post a single code sample and tell us what the error with it is.

Comment: I wish I could show you my error list but I can't upload pics cuz my rep is too low

Comment: the two errors for mystrcat are cannot convert from char to char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with this code.

`mystrcmp`

1. Parameters really should be `const` to prevent accidental modification and allow the passing of string literals.
2. The variable `first` is not declared.
3. The variable `second` is not declared.

`mystrcpy`

1. The return type should be a pointer if you are trying to match the functions in the standard library.
2. You'll need to save the value in `s1` so that it can be returned.
3. You are missing the return statement.

`mystrcat`

1. The return type should be a pointer if you are trying to match the functions in the standard library.
2. The body of the function is totally wrong. Adding two pointer values does not work the way you are expecting. It results in a pointer value of `p1 + p2` and does not access or modify the data they point to.

Below are the modifications necessary to get your homework compiling. I have not tested it or changed much of the logic except for `mystrcat`. I have also included comments from the notes listed above.

```
int mystrlen(const char *pcString) //strlen function
{
    const char *pcStringEnd = pcString;

    while (*pcStringEnd != '\0')
        pcStringEnd++;

    return pcStringEnd - pcString;
}

// added const to parameters
// changed first to s1
// changed second to s2
int mystrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) // strcmp function
{
    while(*s1 == *s2)
    {
        if(*s1 == '\0' || *s2 == '\0')
            break;

        s1++;
        s2++;
    }

    if(*s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0')
        return (0);
    else
        return (-1);
}

// changed return type to a pointer
// added variable to save start of s1
// added return statement
char* mystrcpy(char *s1, const char *s2) // strcpy function
{
    char *start = s1;

    while(*s2)
    {
        *s1 = *s2;
        s2++;
        s1++;
    }

    *s1 = '\0';

    return start;
}

// changed return type
// replaced entire function body
char *mystrcat(char *s1, const char *s2) //strcat function
{
    mystrcpy(s1 + mystrlen(s1), s2);
    return s1;
}
```

Comment: very interesting, why did you put return s1; at the end of the mystrcat fucntion?

Comment: Because [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) returns a pointer to the beginning of the destination string. You should probably read the documentation for each of the functions you are required to implement so that you know how they are supposed to behave.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a definition for variables  first and second (used here:)

```
first++;
second++;
```

You have to  add `char* first = /*Whatever*/, *second = /*Whatever*/` at the beginning of the function `mystrcmp`.

But I think you really made a mistake and you wanted to write

```
s1++;
s2++;
```

Instead of the snippet above (and further in the same function)